# How to create custom styles for workflow activity designer?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm examing posibility of using workflow (workflow foundation-4) designer control in my project. But i need to use it in dark style. 
Is there any chance i could do this?

Comment: Yes, but not easily.  Not easily at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "dark style", but activity designers are quite easy to write. Check out the WF 4 samples project on MSDN - check out the
[WCF/WC Sample package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=87352) (install and check directory *WF\Basic\CustomActivities\CustomActivityDesigners*).

This is a good example of how to use a designer: [Using the ExpressionTextBox in a Custom Activity Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663224.aspx)

One problem I have run accross is that you can't change the style of the actual activity box (apart from opacity and size of course).

Good luck!